# scale text in div layer proportional to container bg-image

Tags: jquery, html, css

following problem:
i have a scrolling page with lots of divs. every div has a bg-image and another div with text in it.

```
 <div id="intro">
            <h1>blabla</h1>
            <p id="text1_1"> another bla bla </p>
            <p id="text1_2"> and again bla </p>
 </div>
```

i handle the bg-image scaling with css3's `background-size: cover;`, when i scale the browser window the text does not stay at the same position and does not resize proportional to the bg-image.
whats the best way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no CSS only method for solving your problem. There is a jQuery plugin which does the trick for you, called [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/).

The problem is that for this to work, the font-size property should be flexible, which right now is not. The only way you can work around this with CSS only - if you are looking for such a solution - is to make media queries and reduce the font-size in smaller viewports, but this only makes the text adaptive.